# Efficient quadtree implementation in python

Tags: python, pointers, optimization, quadtree

For a project I'm working on I'm trying to write some code to detect collisions between non-point particles in a 2D space. My goal is to try to detect collision for a few thousand particles at least a few times per time step which I know is a tall order for python. I've followed this [blog post](http://gamedevelopment.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-use-quadtrees-to-detect-likely-collisions-in-2d-space--gamedev-374) which implements a quadtree to significantly reduce the number pairwise checks I need to make. So where I believe I'm running into issues is this function:

```
def get_index(self, particle):
    index = -1
    bounds = particle.aabb
    v_midpoint = self.bounds.x + self.bounds.width/2
    h_midpoint = self.bounds.y + self.bounds.height/2

    top_quad = bounds.y < h_midpoint and bounds.y + bounds.height < h_midpoint
    bot_quad = bounds.y > h_midpoint

    if bounds.x < v_midpoint and bounds.x + bounds.width < v_midpoint:
        if top_quad:
            index = 1
        elif bot_quad:
            index = 2
    elif bounds.x > v_midpoint:
        if top_quad:
            index = 0
        elif bot_quad:
            index = 3

    return index
```

This function from my initial profiling is the bottleneck and I need it to be blistering fast, because of its high call count. Originally I was just supplying an object axis-aligned bounding box which was working almost at the speed I needed, then realized I had no way of determining which particles may actually be colliding. So now I'm passing in a list of particles to my quadtree constructor and just using the class attribute aabb to get my bounds.

Is there someway I could pass something analogues to a object pointer instead of the whole object? Additionally are there other recommendation to optimize this above code?

Comment: Python already passes by reference (which may be why someone anonymously downvoted your question), so object copying isn't slowing your code down. For each object you could construct a bounding box for it's vector in the timestep. Then you only need to inspect objects where the bounding boxes are in the same quadtree region to see if they intersect to do the detailed check for collision.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if they'll help, but here are a few ideas:

1. v_midpoint and h_midpoint are re-calculated for every particle added to the quadtree.  Instead, calculate them once when a Quad is initialized, then access them as attributes.
2. I don't think the `and` is needed in calculating top_quad. `bounds.x + bounds.width < v_midpoint` is sufficient.  Same for left_quad.
3. Do the simpler checks first and only do the longer one if necessary: bounds.x > v_midpoint vs. bounds.x + bounds.width < v_midpoint
4. `bounds.x + bounds.width` is calculated multiple times for most particles.  Maybe bounds.left and bounds.right can be calculated once as attributes of each particle.
5. No need to calculate bot_quad if top_quad is True. Or visa-versa.

Maybe like this:

```
def get_index(self, particle):
    bounds = particle.aabb

    # right    
    if bounds.x > self.v_midpoint:

        # bottom
        if bounds.y > self.h_midpoint:
            return 3

        # top
        elif bounds.y + bounds.height < self.h_midpoint:
            return 0

    # left
    elif bounds.x + bounds.width < self.v_midpoint:

        # bottom
        if bounds.y > self.h_midpoint:
            return 2

        # top
        elif bounds.y + bounds.height < self.h_midpoint:
            return 1

    return -1
```

Comment: Ohh these are all really good points. I've gone ahead and implemented them and sufficient to say my bottleneck now lies else where. I'm not sure the exact speedup this gives but the cached value for the midpoints, gives 10X or greater when I have large number of particles in my tree